# How to write a function that returns only odd numbers from a nested list?

Tags: racket

How can I write a function `odd-list` that works as follows, using the racket language?

```
(odd-list '((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8) (10 11 12 13))) => ((1 3) (5 7) (11 13))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(require srfi/26)
(define (odd-list lists)
  (map (cut filter odd? <>) lists))
```

Enjoy. :-)